# Is D&D Beyond's full name "Dungeons & Dragons Beyond"?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-beyond

Is the full or official name of [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/) "Dungeons & Dragons Beyond"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that "D&D Beyond" should **not** be expanded into "Dungeons & Dragons Beyond".

Evidence:

- Copyright at the bottom of the page is: "©2017 D&D Beyond".
- The [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCJsu.png) just has "D&D".
- A [search for the phrase "Dungeons & Dragons Beyond" or "Dungeons and Dragons Beyond" on dmsguild.com](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=%22dungeons%20%26%20dragons%20beyond%22%20OR%20%22dungeons%20and%20dragons%20beyond%22&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=dmsguild.com&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) returns no results.

I'm pretty sure it's intended to be stylized as "D&D" rather than stand for "Dungeons & Dragons".

Comment: It’s perhaps worth noting that Dungeons & Dragons has *never* been properly branded with “and”—the ampersand has always been used in every official branding. Even in cases where an ampersand cannot be used for technical reasons—e.g. website URLs, our own tags here—the abbreviation “n” has been preferred over “and.”

Comment: Further to @KRyan's comment, a related question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72125/is-dnd-used-officially-as-an-abbreviation-for-dungeons-and-dragons